# Ubuntu spyder sys.prefix which python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and have installed Spyder after having installed Anaconda.  I have pip installed packages that import fine in the command line, but in the Spyder console they are not found. When I do `sys.prefix` on the command-line I get:

> /home/rick/anaconda2

and in the spyder console I get:

> /usr

command line:

```
$ which -a python
/home/rick/anaconda2/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Shouldn't these be the same? Or are they kept different to allow for multiple envs?

Comment: I have gone into Tools>Preferences>Console>AdvancedSettings  and changed the python executable to Use the following python interpereter to anaconda2/bin/python.  This will work when I am using the python console in spyder, but will crash the Ipython console in spyder.

Comment: Another interesting find here..IF I open spyder with the icon in the Activities menu I get the problem above, but if I open a terminal and type 'spyder' at the command line and it opens that way, I get this response for sys.prefix: '/home/rick/anaconda2'  which is what I'm after..however, I still don't understand why

Comment: It seems you have two versions of Spyder installed, one through Anaconda and another one through `apt-get`. If you want to use Anaconda, I'd recommend you to remove the one you installed with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, removing the second version of spyder that I installed did the trick! Thought they needed to be installed separately